# Convert numerical to categorical in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, numeric, categorical

I have a dataset of internet traffic. There is a ports column I want to convert ports to categorical. This is the code I written to it

```
df2.loc[df2['Src Port'] == 443] = 'HTTPS'
```

Now I want to category all rests ports into category called 'other'. So how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dictionary and `map`:

```
df2['Src Port'] = df2['Src Port'].map({443: 'HTTPS'}).fillna('other')
```

Alternatively, the obvious complement to your approach would be:

```
df2.loc[df2['Src Port'] != 443] = 'other'
```

*NB. you assign to all columns here!*